# JPEG Compression lossless encoder?

Tags: c#, .net, image, compression

I was reading about image compression, but found that the encoder for c# is lossy, is there any way to make a lossless function compressor in c#? I could only find the lossy option ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameters?view=netframework-4.8 )

Comment: There are various TIF formats, some even, I think, losslessly compressed. But by all means do go for PNG as this is widely accepted..

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the Fo-Dicom library at GitHub. It is an open-source library for the use in medical imaging. They have implemented all the lossless JPEG algorithms like Jpeg Lossless, Jpeg-LS and Jpeg2000:
https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/tree/4562544b8742c78b7b6dd49f1e47bc7952690ee5
Fo-Dicom in itself uses the Health-Efferent library (also open source), which is written in C++, but C# wrappers are implemented:
https://github.com/Efferent-Health/fo-dicom.Codecs

Answer (score 0):

Use PNG to have lossless image compression in .NET.
Because PNG is by design (and also standardized by W3C and IETF) is lossless.

For more information, visit official documentation on encoding and decoding PNG using .NET:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-png-image

And for reference, this is the official PNG standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2083

**Update 1**:

I added clarification of supported lossless image compression in .NET.

Comment: only png can be lossless compressed?

Comment: on .NET, the support for lossless image compression only support PNG.

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify more on lossless image compression support in .NET

Comment: o okey thanks, there is some 3 party free option for more images?

Comment: @Greg as far as I know, no. And you are asking for different question, because your main question is for image lossless compression on .NET.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG compression is by design lossy in most cases ("acceptably so") but a lossless standard does exist; you might find that some of the c# snippets on this site get you towards your goal:

https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/applying-lossless-jpeg-transforms.htm